# On Tichonoff's theorem and convergent subnets

Tags: general-topology, limits, nets

The space of functions $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is compact in the topology of pointwise convergence due to Tichonoff's theorem.

Consider the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_n$ defined by $$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{} 0 \quad \text{if } x\in \left[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right] \text{ for } k \text { odd in } \{1,\ldots 2^n\} \\ 1\quad \text{otherwise}\end {array}\right.$$

This sequence should have a convergent subnet. Does someone know how to find such a subnet? Thanks!

Comment: At least we're sure that a subnet limit will have value $0$ at $0$, and $1$ at $1$. A subsequence won't work, that much is clear too.

Comment: The traditional transcription of Тихонов is Tychohoff (although the use of the letter "y" seems to be a bit illogical). However, Тихонов himself seems to have chosen this  transcription. See his early papers in *Mathematische Annalen* which he wrote in German.